# ng-pattern can only applied on input type text?

Tags: angularjs

This is a really simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.11" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myForm">
      <div>
        <input type="number" name="number" ng-model="num" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"/>
        <br>error: {{ myForm.number.$error }}
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="text" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"/>
        <br>error: {{ myForm.text.$error }}
      </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      angular.module('myApp', []);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/LHfc7xmO4pwX2QSGiFsh/preview)

With both using the same `ng-pattern`, only the one with input type `text` work. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5's `number` type is not currently supported by AngularJS. If you put `required` directive in the input control, the validation will be triggered, and you can get the status from `myForm.number.$valid`. Hope it helps.

Comment: so I'm misled by the documentation... http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.number